# Call back for pipes

Tags: windows, pipe

I have created two pipes for communication between child and parent process. One Pipe for STDIN and one for STDOUT.

I want to register for the call back function for STDIN. If any data arrives on the pipe, my Call back should be called. Can it be done in windows. Or Only option is to use threads, one for STDIN and one for STDOUT?

Kindly suggest

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`ReadFileEx` allows you to set up a callback.  But be aware that callback APCs are only processed when your thread enters an alertable wait, they aren't asynchronous like Unix signals.

And the callback is one-shot, your callback handler needs to call `ReadFileEx` again if you're  interested in future data.